# TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property on '$stateChangeStart' event's params

Tags: angularjs, events, angular-ui-router

We have the following function that shows a confirmation dialog to the user when there are unsaved changes and the user tried to navigate away.

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', (event, toState, toParams, __fromState, fromParams) => {

            if (fromParams.userConfirmedRedirect) {
                return;
            }

            const checklistIsActive = $scope.revision &&
                $scope.revision.checklist.status === ChecklistConstants.Status.ACTIVE;
            const stateChangeIsWithinSameChecklist = toParams.id === $scope.checklistId;
            if (checklistIsActive && !stateChangeIsWithinSameChecklist) {

                const queueKey = PromiseQueueKeyGenerator.generateByChecklistId($scope.checklistId);
                if (PromiseQueueService.isInProgressByKey(queueKey)) {

                    event.preventDefault();

                    MessageBox.confirm({
                        title: 'Are you sure?',
                        message: 'Please wait while we save your changes and try again.',
                        okButton: {
                            type: 'danger',
                            text: 'Yes',
                            action() {
                                fromParams.userConfirmedRedirect = true;
                                $state.go(toState.name, toParams, options);
                            },
                        },
                    });
                }

            }

        });
```

This used to work perfectly fine before, but now throws an error (probably after an upgrade or something).

The error is:

```
TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.
  at action(./app/features/checklist/checklist-ctrl.js:517:33)
  at fn(./app/features/message-box/confirm-ctrl.js:13:53)
  at expensiveCheckFn(./node_modules/angular/angular.js:16213:1)
  at $element(./node_modules/angular/angular.js:26592:1)
  at $apply(./node_modules/angular/angular.js:18094:1)
  at ? (./node_modules/angular/angular.js:26597:1)
  at dispatch(/npm/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:41777)
  at s(/login:5:23562)
  at _a(./node_modules/@sentry/browser/dist/index.js:3257:1)
```

The line that it's thrown from is this:

```
fromParams.userConfirmedRedirect = true;
```

I understand the reason for the error, however, I am stuck with a solution.

We need to pass an additional parameter to be available on the next `$stateChangeStart` event in order to make sure that the confirmation only shown once per route change.

I tried using the `options` argument for that:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', (event, toState, toParams, __fromState, __fromParams, options) => {

            if (options.custom.userConfirmedRedirect) {
                return;
            }

            const checklistIsActive = $scope.revision &&
                $scope.revision.checklist.status === ChecklistConstants.Status.ACTIVE;
            const stateChangeIsWithinSameChecklist = toParams.id === $scope.checklistId;
            if (checklistIsActive && !stateChangeIsWithinSameChecklist) {

                const queueKey = PromiseQueueKeyGenerator.generateByChecklistId($scope.checklistId);
                if (PromiseQueueService.isInProgressByKey(queueKey)) {

                    event.preventDefault();

                    MessageBox.confirm({
                        title: 'Are you sure?',
                        message: 'Please wait while we save your changes and try again.',
                        okButton: {
                            type: 'danger',
                            text: 'Yes',
                            action() {
                                options.custom.userConfirmedRedirect = true;
                                $state.go(toState.name, toParams, options);
                            },
                        },
                    });
                }

            }

        });
```

But this approach didn't work.

What are my other options?

Comment: Could use a service to store app state

Comment: @charlietfl true, I can even use redux, but then I need to worry about resetting it as well

Comment: are you able to call event.preventDefault() only after the messageBox is shown and the user clicks 'no'?

Comment: @Austin I am able to call it at any time. What do you suggest?

Comment: I'm suggesting you only call it when the user clicks 'no' on the message box instead of every time, like you're currently doing